# Analycity of f(z)/z

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: If $f(z)$ is analytic, is $f(z)/ z$ ($z$ not equal to zero) analytic?

In principle yes, since $f(z)$ and $1/z$ are holomorphic (analytic) and the product of two holomorphic functions ( $f(z)$ and $1/z$) is holomorphic (analytic). Any "authentic" references for these statements ($1/z$ is holomorphic and the product of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic) would be helpful to validate my answer.

Comment: Generally, if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic, the $f/g$ is holomorphic where $g$ isn't zero

Comment: What is the context of this?  The claims you ask about should be given in most any book/notes that introduces holomorphy.

Comment: I think, it would be the most authentic reference, if you'd prove both statements: both proof aren't so long or surprising. For example $f$ is analytic in $a$ means, that $f$ is generated in a disc around $a$ by a power series.  You have just to verify, that the Cauchy-power of two convergent series is convergent too. And on the other hand, that $\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic, you can prove showing, that it is complex differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reply. I have no books or notes. Just me, the Internet and the mathstack' community. The context is to learn about the conservation of the holomorphic attribute under the operations of addition, subtraction, and product of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Good point Mr. Gergely. I wanted to save space by providing the references for the proofs. Thanks.

Comment: Another useful fact: if $g(z)$ is analytic in a deleted neighborhood of a point $a$ and bounded in a neighborhood of $a$, then it is analytic at $a$.  So, for example, $(\sin z)/z$ is analytic everywhere, including at zero.

Comment: that's called a [meromorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function). it is holomorphic on the open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ that don't contain its poles.

Answer (score 0):

I just found these two references for the statements:

1/z is holomophic : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_analytique

Product is holomorphic: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/214/214S5_0708.pdf ; p.49

Comment: $1/z$ is analytic on $\mathbb C^*$, which is $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. So $1/z$ is not analytic pon $\mathbb C$. In fact, it is undefined at $z=0$.

Comment: and that $f(z) g(z)$ is analytic on $|z-a| < R$ whenever $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic on $|z-a| < R$ is obvious. the same for "holomorphic", and if $g(z)$ is holomorphic, then $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ is holomorphic on any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ where $\frac{1}{g(z)} \ne 0$

Comment: hence Hass Saidane : you need to learn the basic of complex analysis : the definition of "holomorphic" and the Cauchy integral formula, etc.